# JavaFX in eclipse can't find external jars

Tags: java, eclipse, javafx

I am trying to deploy an FXML project as a runnable jar and I am using an external library controlsfx-8.20.7.jar for some custom Dialog Boxes and the application works fine in Eclipse but once I export it as a runnable jar all the operations that involve invoking some methods in the controlsfx jar gives me an error java.lang.ClassNotFoundException

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably didnt extracted all the required libraries, try  right click on your project go to EXPORT -> Runnable JAR file-> choose export destination and in **Library holding** check **"Package required libraries into generated JAR"** after that finish and you will be able to run it without exceptions